# Tough Regex issue

Tags: .net, regex

I need to create a *single* regex (with .NET 3.5 Regex, if that matters) that allows for all three of the following possibilities:

1. `[A-Z]{2,3}`
2. `[A-Z]{2,3}-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}`
3. `[A-Z]{2,3}-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z0-9]{2,3}`

So `BIG`, `BIG-A9`, or `BIG-A09-SD` would match, 
but `BIG-F`, `BIG-A9S-`, or `BIG-A09-S` would NOT match.

I should clarify some things:

- I need to match the entire line, not just a part of it.
- I am trying to provide feedback for a user who is in the process of typing this string into a `TextBox`. Therefore, I am looking for a regex that I can use to test the content of the TextBox whenever it changes. For example, when the user types "A" the feedback should be negative as they have not yet matched case 1. Once they type "AA", the feedback will be positive because they have matched case 1. After typing "AAE", they should still receive positive feedback because they have matched case 1. If they type "AA7", the feedback should go negative. If they then continue typing and enter "AAE-", the feedback should go negative again as they have not met case 2 yet, and have exceeded case 1.

I am pulling my hair out (what little is left).

Does someone out there know how to express this in a way that will work?

Comment: Can you not combine all three expressions with an or `|`? I.e., `[A-Z]{2,3}|[A-Z]{2,3}-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}|[A-Z]{2,3}-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z0-9]{2,3}`

Comment: Why is this tough? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a rule, regular expressions match according to the **leftmost longest rule**, the formal expression of which (from the Posix Standard) is:

> The search is performed as if all possible suffixes of the string were tested for a
>   prefix matching the pattern; the longest suffix containing a matching prefix is chosen,
>   and the longest possible matching prefix of the chosen suffix is identified as the
>   matching sequence.

Each of your three possibilities are extensions of the previous one. Start with your third and longest:

```
[A-Z]{2,3}-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}-[A-Z0-9]{2,3}
```

It has 3 components, each of which is a regular expression in its own right:

- `[A-Z]{2,3}`
- `-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}`
- `-[A-Z0-9]{2,3}`

First you need to *group* each of them:

- `([A-Z]{2,3})`
- `(-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2})`
- `(-[A-Z0-9]{2,3})`

Then, the last two can be combined to for a longer regular expression

- `([A-Z]{2,3})`
- `(-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2})(-[A-Z0-9]{2,3})`

Note that the 3rd segment is optional, if we have the second segment, so use the suffix operator '?' to make it so:

- `([A-Z]{2,3})`
- `(-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2})(-[A-Z0-9]{2,3})?`

Now group the entire second component to indicate that it is a integral piece:

- `([A-Z]{2,3})`
- `((-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2})(-[A-Z0-9]{2,3})?)`

Note that if we have the first component, that entire second component is optional, so again use the suffix operator `?` to indicate optionality:

- `([A-Z]{2,3})`
- `((-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2})(-[A-Z0-9]{2,3})?)?`

And finally, concatenate the two regular expressions to form the final expression:

```
([A-Z]{2,3})((-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2})(-[A-Z0-9]{2,3})?)?
```

There you go. No backtracking and minimal lookahead should be required of the regex engine.

**EDITED TO NOTE** From the O.P.'s comment below, it appears that the desired match is the *entire string*. So...

By default, regular expressions find the **leftmost longest** match in the source string. If you want to match the *entire string* or *entire line*, you need to *anchor* the expression with the metapatterns, `^`, which anchors the match at that position to start-of -line and `$`, which anchors the match at that position end-of-line. So...

- `^abc`, matches a prefix, matching any string starting with `abc` (`abc`, `abcabc`, `abcc`, `aabcdefg`, etc.). It does not match things like `xyzabc`, `ab`, etc.
- `abc$`, similarly, matches a suffix, matching any line ending in `abc` (`abc`, `xyzabc`, etc.). It does not match things like `ab`, `xyzab`, `abcxyz`, etc.
- `^abc$` will *only* match the string `abc` and nothing else.

To match the entire line, take the above regular expression and drop anchor:

```
^([A-Z]{2,3})((-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2})(-[A-Z0-9]{2,3})?)?$
```

That's all there is to it. One should note, however, that the behaviour of `.`, `^` and `$` are dependent on whether or the regular expression is compiled with the `Multiline` or `SingleLine` option. `SingleLine` means that `^` and `$` match only at the beginning and end of the entire string and `.` matches any character but `\n`. `MultiLine` means that `^` and `$` match at the beginning and end of any line in the string and `.` matches any character *including* `\n`.

If you want to fish out the various components that matched, you can add some markup to the regular expression to create *named groups*:

```
(?<prefix>[A-Z]{2,3})((-(?<middle>[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}))(-(?<suffix>[A-Z0-9]{2,3}))?)?
```

Which lets you access the matched groups by name, making for more readable code:

```
Regex rx = new Regex( @"(?<prefix>[A-Z]{2,3})((-(?<middle>[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}))(-(?<suffix>[A-Z0-9]{2,3}))?)?" , RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture );
Match m = rx.Match(s) ;

if ( m.Success )
{
  string prefix = m.Groups["prefix"].Value ;
  string middle = m.Groups["middle"].Value ;
  string suffix = m.Groups["suffix"].Value ;

  Console.WriteLine( "prefix: {0}" , prefix ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "middle: {0}" , middle ) ;
  Console.WriteLine( "suffix: {0}", suffix  ) ;

}
```

*Performance Hint:* using named groups and compiling the regular expression with `RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture` can be a big help, especially when your regular expressions get complex.

If you're new to regular expressions (and even if you're not!), you should read [Jeffrey Friedl](http://regex.info/)'s most excellent *opus*, [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/book.html):

[image: Mastering Regular Expressions]

Comment: This is fantastic and is nearly exactly what I intended. However, this expression matches cases that exceed the first case but that don't match the second case or the third. For example, your expression matches "AAAA" and "AAA-AA-" which was not really my intention. Can the expression be modified so that it doesn't match cases that exceed my specification in this manner?

Comment: @gsusfan: You really should read up on regular expressions as a concept. Unless otherwise  instructed, a regular expression finds the *leftmost longest* match **anywhere** in the string. You haven't specified that the regular expression match only the entire string. To do that, you need to use some metapatterns. See my amended answer.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer!

Answer (score 5):

your regex patterns can be ordered according to the property of being a prefix to others. so try nested optional suffixes:

```
(?:[A-Z]{2,3}(?:-[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}(?:-[A-Z0-9]{2,3})?)?)
```

Comment: +1: This should work. Depending on the intention, `^` and `$` may also be required.

Comment: @acdcjunior: you are right. if applicable (not sure from the OP's description whether they are), the anchors should be used.

Comment: Also, since capturing is probably not desired, I recommend using non-capturing groups `(?:...)`.

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas Carey provided the answer as far as I am concerned. Please see his response for most of the answer. The book is already ordered!

To meet my requirement to provide continuous feedback to the user as they type the input, I registered the following as a TextChanged event handler for Windows Forms.

```
    private void TheTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var rx = new Regex(@"(?<prefix>[A-Z]{2,3})((-(?<middle>[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}))(-(?<suffix>[A-Z0-9]{2,3}))?)?", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
        Match m = rx.Match(textbox.Text);

        if (m.Success)
        {
            string prefix = m.Groups["prefix"].Value;
            string middle = m.Groups["middle"].Value;
            string suffix = m.Groups["suffix"].Value;
            if (prefix != "")
            {
                textbox.BackColor = prefix.Equals(textbox.Text) ? Color.LightGreen : Color.LightPink;
                if (middle != "")
                {
                    string twoparts = prefix + "-" + middle;
                    textbox.BackColor = twoparts.Equals(textbox.Text) ? Color.LightGreen : Color.LightPink;
                    if (suffix != "")
                    {
                        string threeparts = prefix + "-" + middle + "-" + suffix;
                        textbox.BackColor = threeparts.Equals(textbox.Text) ? Color.LightGreen : Color.LightPink;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textbox.BackColor = Color.LightPink;
        }
    }
```

Here is a WPF version, just because.

```
    private void TheTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var rx = new Regex(@"(?<prefix>[A-Z]{2,3})((-(?<middle>[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{1,2}))(-(?<suffix>[A-Z0-9]{2,3}))?)?", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
        Match m = rx.Match(textbox.Text);

        if (m.Success)
        {
            string prefix = m.Groups["prefix"].Value;
            string middle = m.Groups["middle"].Value;
            string suffix = m.Groups["suffix"].Value;
            if (prefix != "")
            {
                textbox.Background = prefix.Equals(textbox.Text) ? Brushes.LightGreen : Brushes.LightPink;
                if (middle != "")
                {
                    string twoparts = prefix + "-" + middle;
                    textbox.Background = twoparts.Equals(textbox.Text) ? Brushes.LightGreen : Brushes.LightPink;
                    if (suffix != "")
                    {
                        string threeparts = prefix + "-" + middle + "-" + suffix;
                        textbox.Background = threeparts.Equals(textbox.Text) ? Brushes.LightGreen : Brushes.LightPink;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            textbox.Background = Brushes.LightPink;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for all of the great answers!! I'll try to be more explicit next time.